# Classic Tokenizer is not working as expected

Tags: solr

I referred [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-ClassicFilter)

I tried to do the same. But it didn't work.

[image]

Any suggestions?

I understand that it works for `I.B.M.` But not for `I.B.M`

Comment: you have to use the ClassicTokenizerFactory with the combination of ClassicFilterFactory. How did you define you fieldType

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I used both. CT and CF are there in the analyzer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below fieldTYpe for your field.

```
<fieldType name="customClassicType" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateWords="1"/>
  <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/> <!-- required on index analyzers after graph filters -->
</analyzer>

<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateWords="1"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here is the output on the analysis page.

[image: Pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: @Gibbs:yes the second screenshot shows the search for I.B.M here there is no dot at the end

Comment: @Gibbs: Please try the provided fieldtype at your solr schema and verify

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thanks